# How to save a table (with its rows, columns and cells) in one single field in a SQL database

Tags: sql

How to save a table (with its rows, columns and cells) in one single field in a SQL database and then display it on a webpage

Comment: Eh? Why would you want to do that? Can we have some context so we can then talk you out of it?

Comment: I really don't understand this. What do you want to do? What do you mean with "table"? Another table from the database? A HTML table? Please be more precise.

Comment: in a database there are no "cells"

Comment: i am saving questions and answers. some answers may require a table with some data. so how and where can i store it?

Comment: In another table that holds related data ?

Comment: yeah i'll use another table for stoarge tables if they were available because the relation is many to many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select table as xml, and the XML result insert/update into the target cell as string (probably varchar).

Answer (score 0):

**A:** Either you design data structures and tables in you DB to hold those structures

or

**B:** you write your "Answers and Tables" to a BLOB (Binary data-field) in the DB.

I suggest you use A, unless you expect to have many or unstructured tables.